# Constraints run successfully in simulator but get errors on device

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an app that runs without any build error or warnings.  The app runs successfully on simulator (no console error) but when I run on my real device I get the following console error:

```
2022-02-07 15:40:30.507950-0400 SalesTax[11923:142076] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000037618b0 UITableView:0x15c871c00.width == 186   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003762850 H:|-(0)-[UITableView:0x15c871c00]   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x15b62cc90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000037637a0 H:|-(20)-[UITextField:0x15c839600]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x15b6138a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000037637f0 UITextField:0x15c839600.leading == UIButton:0x15b6245f0'Country California'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003763ac0 UIStackView:0x15b62cc90.leading == UIButton:0x15b6245f0'Country California'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003763b10 H:[UIStackView:0x15b62cc90]-(18)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x15b6138a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000376c0a0 UIView:0x15b6138a0.width == UIScrollView:0x15c85d200.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000376c410 UILayoutGuide:0x600002d13b80'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.trailing == UIScrollView:0x15c85d200.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000376c460 UIScrollView:0x15c85d200.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x600002d13b80'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003715680 'UISV-canvas-connection' H:[UITableView:0x15c871c00]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x15b62cc90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003768c30 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x15b613dd0.width == 428   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000376c320 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-left' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600002d13b80'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x15b613dd0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000376c3c0 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-right' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x600002d13b80'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x15b613dd0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000037618b0 UITableView:0x15c871c00.width == 186   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
Optional(18.0)
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9
```

Layout is the same on simulator and device, but a dropdown menu title doesn't show its title on my iPhone device.  I know that is a constraint problem, but I can't identify the view object constraints that cause the problem.  Please consider that it's my first time using Xcode and Swift.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for a bit more context?

Comment: add height constraint to your title that is not showing in real device

Comment: title already has height constraint

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

On size inspector, horizontal width of some of my labels constraints, I changed the priority from 1000 to 750.  That removed the error messages.